# Is there a way to remove all Product attributes set on View level, so they all fall back to "All Store View" scope?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, products

I have been working on fixing the product attributes that were imported via CSV files. I noticed that somehow the importers fill in attributes on the store view level, which means the change I made to the `All Store Views` will not be affecting until I manually go through the `Default Store View` and set each applicable to fall back to the Default Value.

Is there a way to just remove all of them (via MySQL or code or admin UI)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the attribute values are kept in the tables `catalog_product_entity_*` where `*` can be `int`, `varchar`, `text`, `datetime`, `decimal`.
All the default values have the field `store_id` = 0 and the store view values have `store_id` the actual store id that is `> 0`.

So you can delete all the values from these tables where `store_id` is not 0.

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_int WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_text WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_datetime WHERE store_id <> 0;
```

But backup your db just to be safe.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Just to make sure.. Is there also a way to set all applicable attributes to programatically check "Use Default Value" without going through each of them? or by removing the entries from those tables will actually make the UI check the check box by default?

Comment: The checkbox is unchecked when there is a specific value for the current store view. Removing the values for all store views except 0 from the db will make all checkboxes checked.

Comment: <> what does this means ?
is it less then & greater then ?

Comment: Yes. It means "different"